# How to locate element to click in a website

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need to fill a form. I am beginning to use Selenium. After logging in with no issues the new screen is coming. There there is a tab on the left side that I need to click in order to open the form that needs to be filled. This tab has the text "Alta registro compra". I cannot find the way to click there.

This is the part of the code that should be working, from the moment when I submit the password (log in), I wait for the element to be loaded with:

```
 <li id="establecimientos1"><a href="/aples/faces/web/registros    /alta_registro0.faces" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left:5px; background-color: #B1C3BE;height: 15px">
                <span style="vertical-align: 5px; cursor: pointer;">Alta registro compra
                </span></a>
        </li>'''
```

here is the website code. I tried already locating with xpath with same result...

```
<form id="j_id24" name="j_id24" method="post" action="/aples/faces/entrada.faces" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id24" value="j_id24" />
    <div id="menu" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px">
    <ul id="menunavlist">
        <li id="establecimientos1"><a href="/aples/faces/web/registros/alta_registro0.faces" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left:5px; background-color: #B1C3BE;height: 15px">
                <span style="vertical-align: 5px; cursor: pointer;">Alta registro compra
                </span></a>
```

I expect that the website gives access to the form so that I can start looking for the fields that need to be filled. However nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Alta registro compra** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#establecimientos1>a[href*='alta_registro0']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='establecimientos1']/a[contains(@href, 'alta_registro0')]/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using a different condition (waiting to be loaded). Yours makes more sense. It's not working though. It behaves like the click is not happening. I tried both methods, xpath and css selector).

Comment: Done! Working! Thank you for your hint. I found the right CSS selector and now is working. Thanks a lot